# custom TOC text overflow

Tags: table-of-contents

After customizing my Table of contents as shown below, my toc overflows onto the footer and doesn't go to the next page.

Here is the toc customization I have done :

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\addvspace{15pt}\bfseries}{\fontsize{13}{13}\bfseries\chtocfont\contentslabel{2.5em}}{\hspace{2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[2.5em]{\addvspace{5pt}\bfseries}{\fontsize{13}{13}\fontseries{bc}\sectocfont\contentslabel{1.25em}}{\hspace{2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]{\addvspace{5pt}\bfseries}{\fontseries{bc}\sectocfont\contentslabel{1.25em}}{\hspace{2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[7.5em]{\addvspace{5pt}\bfseries}{\fontseries{bc}\sectocfont\contentslabel{1.25em}}{\hspace{2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{paragraph}[9.5em]{\addvspace{5pt}\bfseries}{\fontseries{bc}\sectocfont\contentslabel{1.25em}}{\hspace{2.5em}}{\hfill\contentspage}
```

`\chtocfont` is for using Helvetica as a font for the chapter content line, `\sectocfont`  for using the Lucidia Grande as font for the content line.

Here is a screen shot of the issue I am having. Note that some entries from the toc are not shown at all.

the follow link  contains a paste of a tex  example show the problem i have : http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/KZus0jGD

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete example that reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way.

Comment: You're using two conflicting packages: either use `tocloft` or `titletoc`, not both. If I remove `\usepackage{tocloft}` and the `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{...}` line, there is no problem.

Comment: it works just by remove \usepackage{tocloft}. thanks a lot @egreg

Answer (score 1):

The error is in loading both

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

and

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

that fight with each other for the typesetting of the table of contents, with contradictory instructions.

I suggest you to remove the call to the former (and the connected redefinition of `\cftdot`).