# How do you remove vertical spacing of ToC title without tocloft?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to control the vertical spacing of my table contents title, however I'm getting into overflow issues because I'm loading both `tocloft` and `titletoc`. I found a similar case, but just removing `tocloft` just won't do as I need to remove the spacing between the title and the entries.

[custom TOC text overflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121968/custom-toc-text-overflow)

[image: Overflow!]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

    \usepackage{tabto}

    \usepackage{tocloft}
        \setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

    \usepackage{titletoc}
        \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {\vspace{1em}}% <above-code>
            {\MakeUppercase \chaptername\ \thecontentslabel \tabto{1.25in} \MakeUppercase}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

        \titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {\vspace{0.5em}}% <above-code>
            {\tabto{0.5in} \thecontentslabel \tabto{1.25in}}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

        \titlecontents{subsection}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {}% <above-code>
            {\tabto{1.25in} \thecontentslabel \tabto{2.0in}}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `tocloft`, you can patch the `\tableofcontents` command to insert some negative vertical spacing after the heading as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc}{\vspace{-1cm}\@starttoc}{}{}
```

This reduces the space by `1cm`.  The removal of the `tocloft` package, means that the overflow problem disappears.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

    \usepackage{tabto}

    \usepackage{titletoc}
        \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {\vspace{1em}}% <above-code>
            {\MakeUppercase \chaptername\ \thecontentslabel \tabto{1.25in} \MakeUppercase}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

        \titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {\vspace{0.5em}}% <above-code>
            {\tabto{0.5in} \thecontentslabel \tabto{1.25in}}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

        \titlecontents{subsection}% <section-type>
            [0pt]% <left>
            {}% <above-code>
            {\tabto{1.25in} \thecontentslabel \tabto{2.0in}}% <numbered-entry-format>
            {}% <numberless-entry-format>
            {\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc}{\vspace{-1cm}\@starttoc}{}{}

\begin{document}


    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
    \chapter{A Chapter}
        \section{A Section}
            \subsection{A Sub-Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is better than the workaround I came up with. I was just testing the addition of `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-3em}}` at the beginning of the document.

Thank you for your solution.